# Divide and Conquer Algo to find maximum difference between two ordered elements

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Given an array arr[] of integers, find out the difference between any two elements such that larger element appears after the smaller number in arr[].

```
Max Difference = Max { arr[x] - arr[y] | x > y }
```

Examples:

- If array is `[2, 3, 10, 6, 4, 8, 1, 7]` then returned value should be 8 (Diff between 10 and 2).
- If array is `[ 7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2 ]` then returned value should be 2 (Diff between 7 and 9)

My Algorithm:

I thought of using D&C algorithm.
Explanation

```
2, 3, 10, 6, 4, 8, 1, 7

then

2,3,10,6      and     4,8,1,7

then

2,3  and 10,6  and  4,8 and 1,7

then

2 and 3   10 and 6   4 and 8    1 and 7
```

Here as these elements will remain in same order, i will get the maximum difference, here it's 6.

Now i will move back to merege these arrays and again find the difference between minimum of first block and maximum of second block and keep doing this till end.

I am not able to implement this in my code.
can anyone please provide a pseudo code for this?

Comment: Would you please make your question more clear. It seems as if you are trying to implement merge-sort firstly and then achieve something else.

Comment: @shekharsuman    I want maximum of (arr[x]-arr[y]) such that index x > y.

Answer (score 5):

We have `max { A[i] - A[j] |  i > j } = max { A[i] - min { A[j] | j < i } | i }`, which yields
a straightforward O(n) algorithm:

```py
prefix_min = A[0]
result = -infinity
for i := 1 to n - 1:
    # invariant: We have prefix_min = min { A[j] | j < i }
    result = max(result, A[i] - prefix_min)
    prefix_min = min(prefix_min, A[i])
```

Divide & Conquer is conceptionally more complicated, but also leads to a linear time solution (with a higher constant factor).

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Comment: question asked is a divide and conquer algorithm and you have implemented kadane's algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to find the largest Difference LD(A[])

**Complete Psuedocode as desired:**

Divide the array in two parts A1[] and A2[].

```
Find minimum & maximum element in A1[] and LD(A1).
Find minimum & maximum element in A2[] and LD(A2).

LD(A) = max( LD(A1), LD(A2), MAX(A2) - MIN(A1) )
MAX(A) = max( MAX(A1), MAX(A2) )
MIN(A) = min( MIN(A1), MIN(A2) )
```

Base Case (`length(A) == 2`):

```
If A[1] > A[0], 
  LD(A) = A[1] - A[0].
  MAX(A) = A[1]
  MIN(A) = A[0]
else
  LD(A) = 0.
  MAX(A) = A[0]
  MIN(A) = A[1]
```

Note:

```
If (length(A) == 1)
    LD(A) = 0
    MIN(A) = MAX(A) = A[0]
```

Similarly you can calculate the min and max elements in each subarray.

Comment: -Do you think that he asked the same question?Actually,this was the algorithm which he wanted to implement! Your answer doesn't serve the output of his question! Please go through his example once again.

Comment: @shekharsuman He wanted the psuedo-code for his algorithm. I have provided him that.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Can you give a linear time solution ? Write now its running time is O(nlogn).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code in C using Divide and Conquer.
Plz. do feel free to comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct data{
    int min_;
    int max_;
};

struct data crossminmax(int *p,int lo,int mid,int hi){
    int i,min,max;
    struct data temp;

    min = p[mid];
    for(i=mid;i>=lo;i--){
        if(p[i] < min){
            min = p[i];
        }
    }

    max = p[mid+1];
    for(i=mid+1;i<=hi;i++){
        if(p[i] > max){
            max = p[i];
        }
    }
    temp.min_ = min;
    temp.max_ = max;
    return temp;
}

/* MinMax calculates the difference between Biggest and Smallest element  *
 * of an array using divide and conquer principles such that the position * 
 * of Biggest element is always greater than the Samllest element         */

struct data minmax(int *p,int lo,int hi){
    int mid,leftdiff,rightdiff,crossdiff;
    struct data left,right,cross,temp;

    if(lo == hi){
        temp.min_ = p[lo];
        temp.max_ = p[hi];
        return temp;
    }

    mid = (lo+hi)/2;
    left = minmax(p,lo,mid);
    right = minmax(p,mid+1,hi);

    cross = crossminmax(p,lo,mid,hi);
    leftdiff = left.max_ - left.min_;
    rightdiff = right.max_ - right.min_;
    crossdiff = cross.max_ - cross.min_;

    if(leftdiff > rightdiff && leftdiff > crossdiff){
        return left;
    }else if(rightdiff > crossdiff){
        return right;
    }else{
        return cross;
    }
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {5,2,3,10,1,3,16,4,3};
    struct data dt;
    dt = minmax(arr,0,8);
    printf("Max difference = %d, Max Element=%d, Min Element = %d  \n",dt.max_ - dt.min_,dt.max_,dt.min_);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks Nathan & chiwangc for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

largest differance in array

```
condition : - larger number should appear after smaller number
{ 10, 3, 6, 4, 8, 1, 7 }     6
{ 2, 3, 10, 6, 4, 8, 1 }     8
{ 7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2 }         1
{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }               3
{ 4, 3, 2, 1  }              0



#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int n = 7;
  int arr[7] = { 10, 3, 6, 14, 8, 1, 7 };

  int i;
  int max_diff = 0;
  int min = arr[0];

  for( i=0; i<n; i++){
    if( (arr[i] - min) > max_diff ){
      max_diff = arr[i] - min;
    }

    if(arr[i] < min){
      min = arr[i];
    }
  }
  printf("max diff = %d", max_diff);

  return 0;
}
```

//time complexity O(n)

//space   complexity O(1)

for better understanding please visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thPG6eTPf68&t=130s