# Divide and Conquer to find maximum difference between two ordered elements in a two dimensional array

Tags: algorithm

I am now using divide and conquer algorithm to find maximum difference between two ordered elements(it means that A[i][j] − A[k][l] where k>i and l>j) in a two dimension array, like the below one:

[ 0, 3, 6, 4]

[ 9, 3, 1, 6]

[ 7, 8, 5, 6]

[ 1, 2, 3, 4]

So the result is A[1][2] − A[0][0] = 8 - 0 = 8 (not A[0][1] − A[0][0] = 9 - 0 = 9.

The most question are in a single dimensional array, like below question:

[Divide and Conquer Algo to find maximum difference between two ordered elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055608/divide-and-conquer-algo-to-find-maximum-difference-between-two-ordered-elements)

So how can I solve it in a two dimensional array by divide and conquer algorithm?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you better explain the algorithm you used to arrive at `8 - 0 = 8` for the final answer?  This is not clear to me.

Comment: That's why I ask this question. I don't know how to use divide and conquer algorithm to get the final answer.

Comment: I get it now, `8` is your current incorrect result.  Are these arrays sorted in any way?

Comment: I am sorry that the format I write may mislead you. The example I write is not 4 arrays, it is a 4*4 two-dimensional array. My question is for given n*n two-dimensional array A,  how to find maximum A[i][j] − A[k][l] where k>i and l>j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a straight `O(n^2)` solution. In order to calc max of `A[i][j] − A[k][l]`, let's fix `A[k][l]` at the moment. Suppose `A[k][l] = x` in the following graph. Then the candidate set of `A[i][j]` is the shaded rectangle.

So in order to make `A[i][j] − x` maximum. We need to know the max value of the shaded area, this could be calc by simple dynamic programming.

```
+------+------+------+-----+
|      |      |      |     |
|      |      |      |     |
|      |      |      |     |
+--------------------------+
|      |      |      |     |
|      |  x   |      |     |
|      |      |      |     |
+--------------------------+
|      |      |------------|
|      |      |------------|
|      |      |------------|
+--------------------------|
|      |      |------------|
|      |      |------------|
|      |      |------------|
+------+-------------------+
```

---

Define

- `area(i, j) = { A[x][y] | x > i, y > j }`
- `f(i, j) = max( area(i, j) )`
- `g(m, n) = max { f(i, j) - A[i][j] | 1 <= i <= m, 1 <= j <= n }`

Then for a `m*n` matrix, what we want is `f(m, n)`.

And `f(i, j) = max { f(i+1, j), f(i, j+1), A[i][j] }`

So 2 for loops should do the work.